# Is the asymptotic performance of a partition and sort key query in DynamoDB constant, O(1)?

Tags: database, performance, indexing, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

### The example

Take the example of a `Music` table from [https://www.amazon.com/Amazon-DynamoDB-Developer-Guide-Services-ebook/dp/B007Q4JGBM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007Q4JGBM). This table has partition key `Artist` and sort key `SongTitle`.

### The question

If I query for a particular song by a particular artist, is the performance O(1), or does it depend on how many entries that artist has in the database?

### Prior research

The linked documentation indicates constant performance:

> You can access any item in the Music table immediately, if you provide
>   the Artist and SongTitle values for that item.

However, the phrasing is ambiguous and no support is given.

Here, the architecture is described in a way that indicates performance would not be constant:

> DynamoDB uses the partition key value as input to an internal hash function. The output from the hash function determines the partition (physical storage internal to DynamoDB) in which the item will be stored. All items with the same partition key are stored together, in sorted order by sort key value.

I would expect this to result in O(lg m) performance, where m is the number of entries in the database for that particular partition key. This non-constant time would be necessary to search the sorted list of entries for the one with the correct sort key -- in this case, to search for the right `SongTitle`.

### Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you `get` an item by its full primary key - it's constant.

If you query by `Artist`, this means you don't supply a full primary key, then **getting the pointer to the first item is constant**.

Comment: i am not sure if this is true. proof?

Comment: which part troubles you?

Comment: proof, such as some official documentation? for e.g., i'd assume that DDB takes O(lg m), as estimated in question, for `query` for given partition-key and sort-key

Comment: every element can be retrieved in constant time if you provide partition+sort. If you want to query more than one element, thus providing just partition key, you are getting results and are bound to API limitation such as 1MB in size.

Comment: again, my question remains the same. can you point to some official documentation for 'every element can be retrieved in constant time if you provide partition+sort'?

Comment: sorry, same doc as OP highlighted http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html **Partition key and sort key**

Comment: This might be asking too much, but I have to believe that if composite key lookup is constant in performance (and even if it isn't!), there must be some documentation besides something that refers to the specific example of 'Artist' and 'SongTitle'. Better yet, documentation that uses more precise language than the meaningless adjective 'immediately.' Who the heck knows what 'immediately' means in this context?

Comment: DynamoDB, being a fully managed and closed-source system doesn't offer you that. You can read up the document that started it all: http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/files/amazon-dynamo-sosp2007.pdf